# Forms - Select list not working, but check boxes do

Tags: forms, constantcontact

What is the error that is not allowing the below select list to work?

Creating an email sign up form (Constant Contact). Using the Constant Contact form generator, I attempted to change the "mailing lists options" from check boxes to a drop down menu—but doing so caused the contact info to be added to all the mailing lists, and not the single list that was selected.

**Select list code:** (not working)

```
<select>
<option name="Customer Type" ID="">Please select...</option>
<option  value="Architect/Designer" name="Lists[]" id="list_Architect/Designer" />Architect/Designer</option>
<option  value="AV/Media/Broadcast" name="Lists[]" id="list_AV/Media/Broadcast" />AV/Media/Broadcast</option>
<option  value="Command/Control" name="Lists[]" id="list_Command/Control" />Command/Control</option>
</select>
```

**Check box code:** (working)

```
<input type="checkbox"  checked="checked"  value="Architect/Designer" name="Lists[]" id="list_Architect/Designer" />
<label for="list_Architect/Designer">Architect/Designer</label><br />

<input type="checkbox"  value="AV/Media/Broadcast" name="Lists[]" id="list_AV/Media/Broadcast" />
<label for="list_AV/Media/Broadcast">AV/Media/Broadcast</label><br />

<input type="checkbox"  value="Command/Control" name="Lists[]" id="list_Command/Control" />
<label for="list_Command/Control">Command/Control</label><br />
```

Comment: If you're still interested, I'd be happy to post a real answer to this...

Answer (score 0):

you need select to be multiple

```
<select multiple='multiple'>

 <option name="Customer Type" ID="">Please select...</option>
 <option  value="Architect/Designer" name="Lists[]" id="list_Architect/Designer" />Architect/Designer</option>
 <option  value="AV/Media/Broadcast" name="Lists[]" id="list_AV/Media/Broadcast" />AV/Media/Broadcast</option>
 <option  value="Command/Control" name="Lists[]" id="list_Command/Control" />Command/Control</option>
 </select>
```